# Время не изменяется внутри цикла

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
time_to_stop = "22:50"
while True:
    current_time = str(now.hour) + ':' + str(now.minute)
    print(current_time)
    if current_time == time_to_stop:
        break
```

В цикле не изменяется время, минуты остаются такие же и цикл получается бесконечным. Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Перенесите строку `now = datetime.datetime.now()` в цикл.

Comment: @nomnoms12, Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, и не мешает time_to_stop задавать в виде строки, например вот так "22:50". Неужели у вас без этого работало? ;-)

Comment: @passant, я для вопроса написал прямо здесь другой код, забыл поставить скобки. Спасибо за поправку.